# How do I list the N last successful and unsuccessful login attempts for my user when I log in with e.g. ssh on Linux?

Tags: linux, security, ssh, logging, login

This seems like such a basic security feature I'm surprised it's not already standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the last command to show that last logins, maybe put it in /etc/profile.d:

last $USER

However, I would be careful outputting any more to the screen than necessary, because some automated login bits (non-interactive) don't like extra output and fail.  Maybe put in /etc/bashrc and detect if it is a login shell with shopt -q login_shell, and only run if it is.

Comment: .bashrc is sourced for both login and interactive shells wheras .bash_profile (or .profile for other shells) is sourced only for login shells.

Comment: Yes, but if you want it for all users, rather than modifying every .bashrc or .bash_profile on the system, then you would modify /etc/profile, /etc/bashrc, or drop a file in /etc/profile.d.

Comment: right, so replace the dots by /etc/ in my previous comment ;)
"Maybe put in /etc/bashrc and detect if it is a login shell with shopt -q login_shell, and only run if it is." => better use /etc/profile

Answer (score 5):

`last -10`
will show last 10 logins.

Take a look over `man last`